# Android Wear - notification title formatting

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm trying to get the title of my Android Wear notification to display over 2 (or more) lines rather than always 1. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ537.jpg) is an example of what I want, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFWAX.jpg) is what it is doing now. I'm using

```
NotificationCompat.Builder.setContentTitle(CharSequence title)
```

as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)). I've tried inserting newline and/or carriage return characters, and it worked for the text in my notification, but not for the title. I need some way for the title to wrap automatically, or some way for it to recognize newline characters.
Thanks

Comment: I believe the answer lies with choosing a notification style http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html

Answer (score 1):

I think big text is what you want.

```
Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
         .setBigContentTitle(aVeryLongString))
     .build();
```

Comment: This did solve my problem. The formatting was incorrect because I was making an Action using a WearableExtender and setting the PendingIntent of the Action to fire when the notification was clicked. However, that requires there to be an icon on the notification body, even an empty one as I did my case (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018086/android-wear-notification-setcontentaction-not-working)). Apparently, such a content action is not compatible with the BigTextStyle.